# Custom QrCode Scanner after scanning the app is getting close in fragment

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

After scanning QrCode am not getting any result back, in parent activity am implemented onActivityResult  also but app closes after scanning

this is mycode

```
implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.5.0'


public class TestFragment extends Fragment implements  DecoratedBarcodeView.TorchListener{

    private static final int SELECT_PHOTO = 100;
    public String barcode;
    private CaptureManager capture;
    private DecoratedBarcodeView barcodeScannerView;
    private ImageView switchFlashlightButton;
    private boolean isFlashLightOn = false;

    View TestView;
    private Context context;

    public TestFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        TestView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false);

        barcodeScannerView = TestView.findViewById(R.id.zxing_barcode_scanner);

        barcodeScannerView.setTorchListener(this);


        switchFlashlightButton = (ImageView) TestView.findViewById(R.id.switch_flashlight);

        if (!hasFlash()) {
            switchFlashlightButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            switchFlashlightButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    switchFlashlight();
                }
            });
        }


        //start capture
        capture = new CaptureManager((Activity) context, barcodeScannerView);
        capture.initializeFromIntent(getActivity().getIntent(), savedInstanceState);
        capture.decode();



        return TestView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        capture.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }


    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        this.context=context;

    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();

    }

    @Override
    public void onTorchOn() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTorchOff() {

    }

    private boolean hasFlash() {
        return getApplicationContext().getPackageManager()
                .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);
    }

    public void switchFlashlight() {
        if (isFlashLightOn) {
            barcodeScannerView.setTorchOff();
            isFlashLightOn = false;
        } else {
            barcodeScannerView.setTorchOn();
            isFlashLightOn = true;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        capture.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        capture.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        capture.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        capture.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }


}
```

Comment: Please post some stacktrace

Comment: am not getting any error after scanning.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code when you are done scanning and want to return with the data

```
Intent data = new Intent();
String text = "Result to be returned...."
//---set the data to pass back---
data.setData(Uri.parse(text));
setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
//---close the activity---
finish();
```

with this you can get the data in the `onActivityResult` of the calling activity.